# git repository location for Network Manager (Fedora 1)

Tags: git

Where can I find git repo location of NetworkManager component for Fedora?
or being more general,
How to locate components of Fedora on git server?

I am assuming NetworkManager being a component of Fedora have a dedicated git repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedora uses Gnome Network Manager. You can find everything you need [here](http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/). [Here](http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/developers/), instead, you'll find developer hints, as well as instruction on how to get the source code.

To get the source code, you should use git:

`git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.git`

I don't remember if `git` comes with default Fedora installation. However it's easy to install it via `yum`.